# How to extract the bits of larger numeric Numpy data types

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy has a library function, `np.unpackbits`, which will unpack a `uint8` into a bit vector of length 8. Is there a correspondingly fast way to unpack larger numeric types? E.g. `uint16` or `uint32`. I am working on a question that involves frequent translation between numbers, for array indexing, and their bit vector representations, and the bottleneck is our pack and unpack functions.

Comment: You can create a new `ndarray` with the old one as a buffer and a dtype of `uint8`. I'm not sure what the best way to handle byte order is, though. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html might help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with `view` and `unpackbits`

Input:

```
unpackbits(arange(2, dtype=uint16).view(uint8))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

For `a = arange(int(1e6), dtype=uint16)` this is pretty fast at around 7 ms on my machine

```
%%timeit
unpackbits(a.view(uint8))

100 loops, best of 3: 7.03 ms per loop
```

As for endianness, you'll have to look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html and apply the suggestions there depending on your needs.

Comment: This only works for integers in the range of ``uint8``. E.g. ``np.unpackbits(np.array([2**17], dtype="uint16").view("uint8"))`` will return an array of zeros.

Comment: @PietroBattiston it works just fine. What did you expect from stuffing 2**17 into uint16?

Comment: Wait, `np.unpackbits(np.array([2**8], dtype="uint16").view("uint8"))` returns `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]` and this is wrong. What said before is true, only works for integers in the range of `uint8`

Comment: @MarcoAncona, I think this is what Philip meant in his Aug 18 edit: `np.unpackbits(np.array([2**8], dtype=">i2").view(np.uint8))` works just fine.

Answer (score 21):

This is the solution I use:

```
def unpackbits(x, num_bits):
    if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.floating):
        raise ValueError("numpy data type needs to be int-like")
    xshape = list(x.shape)
    x = x.reshape([-1, 1])
    mask = 2**np.arange(num_bits, dtype=x.dtype).reshape([1, num_bits])
    return (x & mask).astype(bool).astype(int).reshape(xshape + [num_bits])
```

This is a completely vectorized solution that works with any dimension ndarray and can unpack however many bits you want.

Comment: You are a true hero @Ross that is some slick numpy magic right there. Much faster than other methods we tried out.

Comment: This doesn't work if the num_bits is very large:
```a = unpackbits(np.array([0x999999999999999999999999999999]), num_bits=256)
b = unpackbits(np.array([0x9999999999999999]), num_bits=256)
print(np.all(a==b))```

Comment: You can see that it fails on the mask for large num_bits:
```num_bits=256
mask = 2**np.arange(num_bits).reshape([1, num_bits])
print(mask)```

Comment: Thanks for finding that @kory, I updated the answer to account for other numpy datatypes like in your example.

Comment: @Ross the issue is that there are too many bits, your example only works for 64 or fewer bits.  My values I gave you are integers.

Comment: @kory because your integer does not fit into a numpy datatype, it uses a generic python object type as the numpy dtype. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271654/stocking-large-numbers-into-numpy-array. If you try out the code for your example, you will see that it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have not found any function for this too, but maybe using Python's builtin struct.unpack can help make the custom function faster than shifting and anding longer uint (note that I am using uint64).

```
>>> import struct
>>> N = np.uint64(2 + 2**10 + 2**18 + 2**26)
>>> struct.unpack('>BBBBBBBB', N)
(2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The idea is to convert those to uint8, use unpackbits, concatenate the result. Or, depending on your application, it may be more convenient to use [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

There is also built-in bin() function, which produces string of 0s and 1s, but I am not sure how fast it is and it requires postprocessing too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for arbitrary arrays of arbitrary uint *(i.e. also for multidimensional arrays and also for numbers larger than the uint8 max value)*.

It cycles over the number of bits, rather than over the number of array elements, so it is reasonably fast.

```
def my_ManyParallel_uint2bits(in_intAr,Nbits):
    ''' convert (numpyarray of uint => array of Nbits bits) for many bits in parallel'''
    inSize_T= in_intAr.shape
    in_intAr_flat=in_intAr.flatten()
    out_NbitAr= numpy.zeros((len(in_intAr_flat),Nbits))
    for iBits in xrange(Nbits):
        out_NbitAr[:,iBits]= (in_intAr_flat>>iBits)&1
    out_NbitAr= out_NbitAr.reshape(inSize_T+(Nbits,))
    return out_NbitAr  

A=numpy.arange(256,261).astype('uint16')
# array([256, 257, 258, 259, 260], dtype=uint16)
B=my_ManyParallel_uint2bits(A,16).astype('uint16')
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```