# Convert Bitstring (String of 1 and 0s) to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bitstring

I have a pandas Dataframe containing 1 columns which contains a string of bits eg.`'100100101'`. i want to convert this string into an numpy array.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

Using

```
features = df.bit.apply(lambda x: np.array(list(map(int,list(x)))))
#...
model.fit(features, lables)
```

leads to an error on `model.fit`:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The Solution that works for my case i came up with due to marked answer:

```
for bitString in input_table['Bitstring'].values:
    bits = np.array(map(int, list(bitString)))
    featureList.append(bits)
features = np.array(featureList)
#....
model.fit(features, lables)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a string `s = "100100101"`, you can convert it to a numpy array at least two different ways.

The first by using numpy's [`fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) method.  It is a bit awkward, because you have to specify the datatype and subtract out the "base" value of the elements.

```
import numpy as np

s = "100100101"
a = np.fromstring(s,'u1') - ord('0')

print a  # [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```

Where `'u1'` is the datatype and `ord('0')` is used to subtract the "base" value from each element.

The second way is by converting each string element to an integer (since strings are iterable), then passing that list into `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np

s = "100100101"
b = np.array(map(int, s))

print b  # [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```

Then

```
# To see its a numpy array:
print type(a)  # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print a[0]     # 1
print a[1]     # 0
# ...
```

Note the second approach scales significantly worse than the first as the length of the input string `s` increases.  For small strings, it's close, but consider the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) results for strings of 90 characters (I just used `s * 10`):

```
fromstring: 49.283392424 s
map/array:   2.154540959 s
```

(This is using the default `timeit.repeat` arguments, the minimum of 3 runs, each run computing the time to run 1M string->array conversions)

Comment: Note that `np.array(map(int, s))` is sufficient - it isn't required to build a `list` first... Also, it's not exactly intuitive, but `np.fromstring(s, 'i1') - 48` is about 50% faster...

Comment: @JonClements performance turns out to be much worse for longer lists -- thanks for the note!

Comment: @JonClements I don't think this is still true in Python 3.x. Now that map returns a map object (iterator), you either have to wrap in `list` or use `np.fromiter(map(int, s))`

Answer (score 2):

One pandas method would be to call apply on the df column to perform the conversion:

```
In [84]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'bit':['100100101']})
t = df.bit.apply(lambda x: np.array(list(map(int,list(x)))))
t[0]
Out[84]:
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [`unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html)

```
>>> np.unpackbits(np.array([int('010101',2)], dtype=np.uint8))
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

And more generally:

```
>>> a = np.array([[2], [7], [23]], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> a
array([[ 2],
       [ 7],
       [23]], dtype=uint8)
>>> b = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

If you need more than 8 bits, check out [How to extract the bits of larger numeric Numpy data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296035)