# using numpy to convert an int to an array of bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need a way to convert 20 million 32 and 64-bit integers into corresponding bit arrays (so this has to be memory/time efficient). Under advice from a different [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296281/8747) here on SO, I'm attempting to do this by using [`numpy.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html).  While experimenting with this method I ran into unexpected results:

```
np.unpackbits(np.array([1], dtype=np.uint64).view(np.uint8))
```

produces:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

I would expect the `1` element to be the last one, but not in the middle.  So I'm obviously missing something that preserves the byte order.  What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't see documentation proving this, but I assumed that when I create an array of type int64 and populate it with data smaller in size, every element would be cast into a long.  I.e. an equivalent of cast in C, which should pad higher order bits with `0`s.

Comment: 20 million! But I hope not hand edited O_o

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18296281/8747) suggests you read [this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I can't.  `np.unpackbits` expects a byte array

Comment: @Robᵩ: that's the question/answer I got the idea from.  I did look at that link and I didn't think it applied here because my data (`1`) is generated on the same computer that is running the python process.  I can take another look for other cues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `dtype='>i8'`, like so:

```
In [6]: np.unpackbits(np.array([1], dtype='>i8').view(np.uint8))
Out[6]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

Reference:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html

Comment: D'oh!.  Ok, I've should've read past the first couple paragraphs.

Comment: Though I still don't understand why I have to do this in my case  since the data is generated and consumed under the same memory architecture.

Comment: Because your PC is little-endian, and you've asked for a big-endian representation.

Comment: "you've asked for a big-endian representation"   My initial code doesn't make any byte order requests.   Does `view` by default assume big-endiannes of the underlying data?  I thought `view(np.uint8)` resulted in simply byte-by-byte read of memory, which would mean that the data there was already in big-endian order (so what imposed that order on a little-endian system).

Comment: I mean in your question, *you*, not your program, asked for a big-endian representation. The representation you objected to was little-endian.