# Is it possible to enforce integer operations in numpy.linalg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, largenumber

If one uses `np.linalg.solve` to solve linear equations, the result has `dtype=float`.

While this is ok for "small" integers, larger ones result in wrong results:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1000000000000,2000000],[3000000000000,4000000]])
x = np.array([1000000,2000000])
np.linalg.solve(A, A @ x)
```

results in

```
array([1000000.      , 1999999.999872])
```

My question is not, why the error occurs, I am aware of that. I also know that the limit for numpy integers is determined by the C integers.

But rather, **is there a way of using/enforcing the use of large(r) integers in `np.linalg`?**

I found this: [Stocking large numbers into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271654/stocking-large-numbers-into-numpy-array) , but this won't work in `np.linalg.solve`:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    401     signature = 'DD->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'dd->d'
    402     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 403     r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    404 
    405     return wrap(r.astype(result_t, copy=False))

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc solve1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[np.linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve) is a wrapper around [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK):

> The solutions are computed using LAPACK routine _gesv.

BLAS/LAPACK is all about floating-point computations! Some integer-based functionality might be supported in commercial implementations (e.g. Intels MKL) and there exists a very limited [experimental branch](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/tree/integer_datatype) on OpenBLAS.

But numpy supports multiple BLAS/LAPACK-backends and therefore only supports what's supported everywhere. And these are the floating-point based operations.

For the curious, you might read a bit within [umath_linalg.c.src](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/de06954b19a6c0980d48e4397adabfd15d808660/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L165) where all those types are easy to recognize. Having these *typed source-code* it's easy to see, why some *np.object*-based array won't do.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you probably want to use [mpmath](http://www.mpmath.org/doc/current/) instead of numpy. It has [linear algebra routines](http://www.mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html#linear-algebra).