# Why numpy.sum on dataframe columns return inf?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with columns of type float64

I try to compute apply sum function on some columns by `numpy.sum`

When I active the function `np.sum(x[col_name])`  I receiving the result of  'inf'

But when I check where is the 'inf' value by `np.where(np.isinf(x[col_name]))` I received empty results.

So, What I do wrong...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the data is restricted. I look on the data, the data do not contain any inf number

Comment: Then I don't know what to say much more. Have a look at np.nansum: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html It treats NaNs as 0

Comment: Ok, After I digging in the data I found number like 1.79600000007e+308 the np is not recognized this number as nan and not as inf,

Comment: What dtype is your data? Max you can do with np.float64 is 1.7976931348623157e+308 according to np.finfo()

Comment: float64 I need to replace it

Comment: Try this: replace float64 with dtype=object

Comment: This solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that one of the numbers in your data, is bigger than the max `np.float64` accepts. If you run, `np.finfo(np.float64)`, you'll see the biggest number this dtype accepts:

```
Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37272717/4014051 python objects use an arbitrary length implementation, therefore the solution would be to make the dtype of your array `object`. This means that your code will be slower overall, as your data are not numpy objects, but presumably it will output the correct sum.