# I need to display a large integer in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types, jupyter-notebook

I'm teaching a kid mathematics and programming with the chess-rice story,(you know, that one that the king pays with rice to the guy that invented chess), using python and jupyter notebook, the thing is I need to display a table with columns i, and 2**i with i from 0 to 64, but when I get to 64 the size of the number is too big for a numpy array, here is the code

```
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

casilla = arange(1,65,1)
arroz = power(2,casilla)
casilla_arroz = pd.DataFrame(arroz,columns = ['Numero de granos de arroz'], index = casilla)
casilla_arroz.index.name = 'Numero de casilla'

display(casilla_arroz)
```

Any fix for this?

Comment: Are ```power``` and ```display``` functions?

Comment: Please provide them too if yes

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271654/stocking-large-numbers-into-numpy-array. Or maybe, as you're "teaching a kid mathematics and programming", not use numpy, as basic Python integer have unlimited size.

Comment: No, power is from numpy and display is from jupyter notebook

Comment: @EricCardozo just use the link above, `casilla = arange(1,65,1, dtype='object')` solves the issue

Comment: Already solved, so so thanks you! man

Comment: @EricCardozo if you solved problem then you could put solution as answer - other people can be interested how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`casilla = arange(1,65,1, dtype='object')` solves the issue