# Operating on numpy array gives incorrect values for large numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer-overflow

I need to operate on some pretty large numbers. Here, I am trying to take the cube of a large number inside an array.

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([149597500000,3,4],dtype=np.int64)
print(array**3)
```

This gives

```
[4258029614102052864                  27                  64]
```

The second 2 values are correct, but the first one is off by many orders of magnitude. By contrast,

```
print(149597500000**3)
```

gives

```
3347904087604984375000000000000000
```

which is the correct result. Is this related to integer overflow? If so, why doesn't performing the operation outside the array also cause an overflow? How can I work around this problem? Sorry if this is a basic question; I never learned Python in a formal way.

Comment: If you want such large numbers, why do you explicitly request 64 bit ints?

Comment: I thought that's the highest it goes. I tried int128, but it said numpy has no attribute 'int128'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the number of bits in the first number to the cube is at least 3*log2(149597500000)+1=113.
This does not fit in a 64 bits

```py
a = 149597500000
b= a**3
print(a.bit_length(), b.bit_length())
```

returns: 38, 112

you can store that bigs number in numpy using either dtype=object or np.float64, see [Stocking large numbers into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271654/stocking-large-numbers-into-numpy-array)

Comment: Thanks, I switched to float64, and it worked.